# Why the "hello, world" is not output to the console?

Tags: scala

I'm just learning scala, and I wrote the "hello,world" program like this:

```
object HelloWorld {
    def main(args: Array[String]) { 
        println("Hello, world!") 
    } 
}
```

I saved it to a file named "helloworld.scala"

Now I run it in the console:

```
scala helloworld.scala
```

But nothing outputed. I thought it will output "Hello, world". Why?

**PS**

If I modify the content to:

```
println("Hello, world")
```

and run again, it will output "hello,world".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

if you want to run your code as a script (by using scala helloworld.scala) you have to tell scala where your main method is by adding the line

```
  HelloWorld.main(args)
```

to your code

the second option you have is compiling the script by using `scalac helloworld.scala`
and then calling the compiled version of your class using `scala HelloWorld`

Answer (score 12):

You have two options.

### Compile and Run:

As in Java you should have a `main`-method as a starting point of you application. This needs to be compiled with `scalac`. After that the compiled class file can be started with `scala ClassName`

```
scalac helloworld.scala
scala HelloWorld
```

### Script:

If you have a small script only, you can directly write code into a file and run it with the `scala` command. Then the content of that file will be wrapped automagically in a `main`-method.

```
// hello.scala, only containing this:
println("Hello, world!")
```

then run it:

```
scala hello.scala
```

Anyway I would recomment to compile and run. There are some things, that are not possible in a "Scalascript", which I do not remember right now.

Comment: When running a compiled Scala program, you sometimes must add "-cp ." to include the current directory so that the .class files could be found: scala -cp . HelloWorld